# How to find the script location where the called proc resides?

Tags: tcl

The script  have sourced N number of files..,

```
source file 1
source file 2
.
.
source file N
```

when  particular procedure A called ., Its actually present in most of the sourced files., anyway the last sourced file containing that proc A will do the function.,
how to find which file  containing the proc is used when i call the proc ?
Any code i can use to achieve it ?

Comment: It's a concrete, but still somehow a very generic, question. Some information on why you want this might help us provide a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way (assuming Tcl 8.5 or 8.6) is to use an execution trace to call `info frame` to get the details of the call stack.

```
trace add execution A enter callingA
proc callingA args {
    set ctxt [info frame -1]
    if {[dict exists $ctxt file] && [dict exists $ctxt proc]} {
        puts "Called [lindex $args 0 0] from [dict get $ctxt proc] in [dict get $ctxt file]"
    } elseif {[dict exists $ctxt proc]} {
        puts "Called [lindex $args 0 0] from [dict get $ctxt proc] (unknown location)"
    } else {
        # Fallback
        puts "Called [lindex $args 0 0] from within [file normalize [info script]]"
    }
}
```

There's quite a bit of other information in the dictionary returned by `info frame`.

---

### For Tcl 8.4

In Tcl 8.4, you don't have `info frame` and Tcl doesn't remember where procedures are defined by default. You still have execution traces though (they were a new feature of Tcl 8.4) so that's OK then. (We have to be a bit careful with `info script` as that's only valid *during* the `source` and not after it finishes; procedures tend to be called later.)

To get where every procedure is defined, you have to intercept `proc` itself, and to do so early in your script execution! (Procedures defined before you set up the interceptor aren't noticed; Tcl's semantics are purely operational.) Fortunately, you can use an execution trace for this.

```
proc procCalled {cmd code args} {
    if {$code==0} {
        global procInFile
        set procName [uplevel 1 [list namespace which [lindex $cmd 1]]]
        set procInFile($procName) [file normalize [info script]]
    }
}
# We use a leave trace for maximum correctness
trace add execution proc leave procCalled
```

Then, you use *another* execution trace on the command that you want to know the callers of to look up what that command is called, and hence where it was defined.

```
proc callingA args {
    # Wrap in a catch so a lookup failure doesn't cause problems
    if {[catch {
        set caller [lindex [info level -1] 0]
        global procInFile
        set file $procInFile($caller)
        puts "Calling [lindex $args 0 0] from $caller in $file"
    }]} {
        # Not called from procedure!
        puts "Calling [lindex $args 0 0] from within [file normalize [info script]]"
    }
}
trace add execution A enter callingA
```

Comment: @Donal.., My company struck with 8.4., so i cannot use that ??

Comment: @Downey_HUff Well, you're now using an unsupported version. :-) We stopped support for 8.4 last summer with the 8.4.20 release (which just rolled up a few fixes that had trickled in). I'll have a bit of a think about how to do it in 8.4, but “not obvious” is the defining feature here…

Comment: @Downey_HUff Try that.